# cmake include full directory paths

Tags: c++, cmake, include

I have a project which is the following:

```
project/
├── apps
│   ├── app_a
│   ├── app_b
│   ├── app_c
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── common
│   ├── some_data.cpp
│   ├── some_data.h
│   ├── some_data_a
│   ├── some_data_b
│   ├── some_data_c
└── └── CMakeLists.txt
```

I would like to include directory `common` which contains some_data.h(cpp) and directories some_data_* which named targets `some_data_a`, `some_data_b`, `some_data_c`.

In root CMakeLists.txt I tried to add:

```
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

So, it works. For example in my `app_a/src/app_a.h` I can write include like this:

`#include "common/some_data_a/some_data_a.h"`

The problem is that I don't understand how to rewrite `include_directories` from main `CMakeLists.txt` to `common/CMakeLists.txt` using `target_include_directories`? (not just include_directories, I want to delete that string from main CMakeLists.txt).

It is important that I can still able to include the full path. For example in file `apps/app_a/app_a.h`:

`#include "common/some_data_a/some_data_a.h"`

not just:

`#include "some_data_a/some_data_a.h"`

I also tried to write it like this:

`target_include_directories(common INTERFACE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})`

But it doesn't work

Comment: `target_include_directories( common PUBLIC  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})`  but remember that your targets need to link to common  `target_link_libraries(app_a PUBLIC common)`

Comment: common is an interface that includes sub-directories: `add_subdirectory(some_data_a)` and etc, it doesn't need to be PUBLIC. target_link_libraries is already included in app directories like this: `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE common)`

Answer (score 0):

Solution. Just put this in common/CMakeLists.txt:

```
target_include_directories(common INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/..)
```

And add `common` to `target_link_libraries` in `some_data_a/CMakeLists.txt`